# StringBuffer into String in Java Applet

Tags: java, string, applet, stringbuffer

I have the following source code of a Java Applet:

```
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Displaytext extends JApplet {

public void init() {
    try {
        AutomatedTelnetClient telnetClient = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
        telnetClient.connect();

        StringBuffer text = telnetClient.sendCommand("display gps");
        telnetClient.disconnect();

        //String answer = "Testing";
        String answer = text.toString();
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(answer);
        getContentPane().add(lbl);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
}
```

When I execute the .html file I only get an empty screen. However, if I insert a normal String into the JLabel ("Testing") instead of converting the StringBuffer to String, I get the word "Testing" in the screen. I have also checked and the StringBuffer text variable has the corresponding return value of the telnetClient.sendCommand() method. The following code works perfectly:

```
package m2mcom.web;
import m2mcom.entities.AutomatedTelnetClient;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Simple {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        AutomatedTelnetClient telnetClient = new AutomatedTelnetClient();
        telnetClient.connect();

        StringBuffer text = telnetClient.sendCommand("display gps");
        telnetClient.disconnect();
        System.out.println(text.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
}
}
```

Why does this happen? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am inside the method init() of the Applet? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your telnet client library needs to somehow flush the received output following `sendCommand()`. Currently it looks like your `StringBuffer` is empty.

It's nothing to do with running within an applet etc. (unless the telnet library *itself* has problems with being applet-constrained, which is always possible)

Answer (score 0):

is not good to use commands with remote calls in init () method,
try this after viewing the applet, preferably on a thread.

```
new Runnabled(){
public void run(){ 
     //call your method here 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain about what your AutomatedTelnetLibrary is, but I found one in [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/meteorafhd/source/browse/trunk/deployServer/src/main/java/com/deployServer/util/AutomatedTelnetClient.java?r=1421) that seems to match your format. If this isn't what you used, please post what you used.

```
    public String sendCommand(String command) {
            try {
                    write(command);
                    return readUntil(prompt + " ");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Bottom line is, sendCommand returns a String, you are setting it to an uninitialized StringBuffer. As a result, I think your StringBuffer isn't initializing right. I'm actually surprised this code compiles at all... Try this:

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer(telnetClient.sendCommand("display gps"));
```

Comment: This is my sendCommand() method, so the StringBuffer is initialized.

Comment: public StringBuffer sendCommand(String command) {
  try {
   write(command);
   return readUntil(prompt + " ");
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: Can you edit your post and put that code into the main question? Also, please include the readUntil function.